# Packaging a Java software for professional use

Tags: java, packaging

i have developed a small project in java.
i want to know how to package my software? i.e. make a window installer(msi) or .exe application from those .java or .class files? OR if its not possible in Java then what to do?

Comment: What are you developing: application with ui, service, web application?

Comment: Obviously an application with UI.

Comment: @Mob why is it obvious? Server app and services don't necessarily need an UI.

Comment: its a game that means app with UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most people just package the application as a jar... You could however take a look [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html) for more information.

If you 100% need a .exe, there are a couple options available:

[launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

[Exe4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/exe4j/overview.html)

[JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

[jexepack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)

However, you may want to do some research on these before using them, as I'm not sure how up to date they are.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) as the 'one click' installation solution for Windows, OS X & *nix.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) for this purpose, take a look at [this](http://www.devx.com/java/Article/30287/1954) example.